# Jquery inputmask submit "null" text when textbox is blank/empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-inputmask

I am using jquery.inputmask.js in my project

```
$("input[type=text].integral").inputmask({ alias: "numeric", groupSeparator: ",", autoGroup: !0, clearMaskOnLostFocus: !1, autoUnmask: true, removeMaskOnSubmit: true });
```

It works fine when displaying or editing
It also remove groupseparator when submit values.
ex
    if textbox has 1,000.10 value 
    it submit 1000.10 to server.

But when we remove value from textbox it submit value as "null".
I want to submit "" to server.
Is there any option or event to remove.

I tried onUnMask and oncleared event it gives "" on console log or alert at client side.
but submit "null" to server.

Comment: url https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Answer (score 0):

In latest version there is an option called "[nullable](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask#nullable)" so that it sends an empty string instead of null:

> **nullable**
>   Return nothing when the user hasn't entered anything.
>   Default: true